# slice chart bar into two in cognos

Tags: charts, slice, cognos

I need assistance on Chart in Series (primary axis), I need to create a condition that will slice the chart bar into two separate bars based on the measure condition

It can be a filter or tuple or calculation. I will have to create two bars: one when the measure is negative and the other when the measure is positive ('Overdue' and 'Pending')

The chart is based on Cube.
Dimension:  Action (Source: 'Action Code', Label: 'Action Desc')

The measure: 'Days Between' which is the number of days between the Action date and current date.

Example: for the Medical Action, I need to separate it in 'Overdue' and 'Pending'

Comment: Hi Jackman,
Could you provide more detailed scenario? Any table example?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather generic so the answer will be the same. Birt data sets enables both filtering and adding computed columns. You need to specify only what you want to filer and how you want to calculate it.
Then create simple chart displaying filtered/calculated data.